# < and > symbols don't appear using mathpazo and Memoir

Tags: fonts, math-mode, memoir, mathpazo

I'm using the `memoir` document class to write some documents for my master's program, including my thesis. I decided to use the font `mathpazo` (Palatino) because I think it looks awesome, but when I try to write some inequalities, the symbols less than and greater than (`<` and `>`) don't appear after compilation and there are NO errors, just a bunch of warnings.

So, if I want to write the expression:

```
\begin{equation}
a<1 %also when I use $a<1$
\end{equation}
```

And the output:

[image: < symbol missing!]

The symbol `<` isn't there! The only workaround for this is to use `\textrm{<}`, but I guess it looks a little bit different. The most relevant warnings are shown below:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/pplx/bx/sc' undefined(Font) using `T1/pplx/bx/n' instead on input line 32.
    Class memoir Warning: The material used in the headers is too large
(15.48003pt) for the given head height (14.5pt), it is recommended to
either increase the head height or redesign the header
(in both cases you will find help in the memoir manual). on input line 35.
```

I have both `amsmath` and `amsmath` packages loaded. Here is the MWE (pretty large, sorry):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openany,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Gráficos
\usepackage[top=4cm,right=2.5cm,left=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,calc,graphicx,soul,fourier}
\usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{parskip}
 \newcommand\missing[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}}
% \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} %Fuente
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz} %Dibujo
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} %Dibujo
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} %Dibujo
%opening

\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\author{DOlor Sit amet}
\firmlists*
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Código}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Índice de Códigos Fuente}

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    tabsize=4,
    rulecolor=,
    literate={ó}{{\'o}}1
         {á}{{\'a}}1
         {é}{{\'e}}1
         {º}{{\textdegree}}1
         {ú}{{\'u}}1,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    language=octave,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=true,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        showtabs=false,
        name=Feedservoplot
        showspaces=false,
        texcl=false,
        inputencoding=latin1,
        numbers=left,
        firstnumber=auto,
    showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
        escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  %Alineado óptico
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{-1.8em}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.8em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}

\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\makeatletter
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{%
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
\colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{%
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[0cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{daleif1}

\makechapterstyle{daleif12}{
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedright ##1\par}
}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin20pt% change 20 pt according to your needs
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \setlength\itemindent{-40pt}% change using the inverse of the length
% used before
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\makeatother

%%=================%%
%%Header and footer%%
%%=================%%
\makepagestyle{tesis2}
\makepsmarks{tesis2}{%
  \createmark{section}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
   \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{}

  }

\makepagestyle{TOC}
\makepsmarks{TOC}{%
  \createmark{section}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
   \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{}

  }

\makeevenhead{TOC}{}{}{\bfseries
\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{TOC}{}{}{\bfseries
\rightmark}
\makeevenfoot{TOC}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{TOC}{}{\thepage}{}
\makefootrule{TOC}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{0pt}
\makeheadrule{TOC}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\makepagestyle{BIB}
\makepsmarks{BIB}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
   \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{}

  }

\makeevenhead{BIB}{}{}{\bfseries
Referencias}
\makeoddhead{BIB}{\bfseries Referencias}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{BIB}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{BIB}{}{\thepage}{}
\makefootrule{BIB}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{0pt}
\makeheadrule{BIB}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\makeevenhead{tesis2}{\bfseries\textsc{Sección
\thesection:}}{}{\bfseries
\rightmark }
\makeoddhead{tesis2}{\bfseries \textsc{Sección \thesection:}}{}{\bfseries
\rightmark}
\makeevenfoot{tesis2}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{tesis2}{}{\thepage}{}
\makefootrule{tesis2}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{0pt}
\makeheadrule{tesis2}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage[activeacute,spanish] {babel}
\renewcommand\shorthandsspanish{}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\usepackage[inner]{showlabels}
\showlabels{cite}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}

\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}

\tableofcontents{\pagestyle{tesis2}}
\pagestyle{TOC}
 \newpage
 \listoffigures
\pagestyle{tesis2}

 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:

\begin{equation}
 a<0
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please explain why you are using both `fourier` and `mathpazo` at the same time? They are the culprit. Besides it has nothing to do with `memoir`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a<0
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the problem with fourier package by providing the following lines just before `\begin{document}`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{<}{\mathrel}{letters}{'074}
\DeclareMathSymbol{>}{\mathrel}{letters}{'076}
```

So, the `>` and `<` will be taken from `cmmi` font.