# "greater than" and "less than" not showing up in compiled document

Tags: math-mode, symbols, lyx, classicthesis

I try to write a inline formula including a greater than sign:

```
$A < B$
```

If I use the above formula in an empty document it works fine, but in my full document it will just not show up. But I can see the additional space that is included due to the presence of the "greater than" sign.

I am using *LyX* with the *classicthesis* format.

Any Ideas where I could start looking?

**Solution:**

I've found the solution. I have set the default roman font in the *LyX* document, which I did not want to.

```
\font_roman utopia
```

This has caused the problem.

As for the minimal working example. I did not find a good way to do this with LyX, as it is not generating soucecode as Latex does. And LyX documents are not mentionend in the default MWE article.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you have in your preamble? (`Document->Setting->Preamble`)

Comment: Provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: And by the way,  welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: My preamble has \usepackage{acronym}. Is there a way to upload the minimal example on this website?

Comment: First, see the link of Svend Tveskæg and edit your question afterwards.

Comment: The problem occurs because of a conflict between `classicthesis` and the `fourier` package, which is loaded because you've set Utopia as the Roman font. Set the  font back to Default and things work fine.

Comment: Please do not link to an external zip file. Instead, please edit your question to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate of  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122544/and-symbols-dont-appear-using-mathpazo-and-memoir since `classicthesis` loads `mathpazo`.

Comment: Ah. Torbjørn was faster than me. Thank You. Can I somehow mark the question as solved?

Comment: I added an answer, accepting it (by clicking the checkmark next to it) marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because of a conflict between `classicthesis` and the `fourier` package, which is loaded because you've set Utopia as the Roman font. Set the Roman font to Default in Document --> Settings --> Fonts, and things should work fine.