# mathematical operator disappear

Tags: equations, math-operators

I have a problem with mathematical operators such as "=", "+" etc.
Whenever I type them within a mathematical environment (equation, eqnarray, in line equations via $...$, displayed equation via $$...$$) they are not then displayed on the pdf version.
I am using the packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

And if I type:

```
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[f_{0}\left(t\right)\right] = 0
\end{equation}
```

I don't get the signal "="

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[f_{0}\left(t\right)\right] = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please post a _complete_ small document that has the problem, and show the log you get: we can not say much from an incomplete fragment

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
... \begin{equation}
 \mathbb{E}\left[f_{0}\left(t\right)\right] = 0

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{fourier}`

Comment: this problem with fourier has been reported before; one such question: [< and > symbols don't appear using mathpazo and Memoir](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122544/579)

Answer (score 5):

Never pile up font package loading. The `fourier` package uses math fonts with a different encoding from the standard, so it changes several slot positions.

On the other hand, the `lxfonts` use the standard encodings for math symbols, so loading `fourier` will have strange effects like the one you're describing.

By the way, your package loading order is a bit confused. And you definitely don't need `\left` and `\right` in that equation.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lxfonts}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}% <--- do you really need it?

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[f_{0}(t)] = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure the result is really beautiful, though.

---

You might try the very recent `newtxsf` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{newtxsf}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}% <--- do you really need it?

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

Some words before the equation so to see the
effect we get
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[f_{0}(t)] = 0
\end{equation}
And something after it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Talking about the loading order of packages, is there a preferable/correct order of loading [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel), [`fontenc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc), and [`inputenc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/inputenc)?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I usually have `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `babel`. Surely `babel` should go after `inputenc` in case non Latin alphabets are required; years ago, loading `inputenc` after `fontenc` might have strange effects in some cases (not reproducible any more, I believe).